# Routing docker conainter to path using port 80

Tags: networking, nginx, docker

I have a docker image that I can access via `domain.com:8080/` from any computer. But I cant get it redirect to `domain.com/service/`

UPDATED: found my answer, see below.

Comment: So you want to redirect `domain.com:8080` to `domain.com/service/`? You can do that in the Nginx on docker right? Just make sure the server at `domain.com:8080` sends an HTTP 301 back to the client.

Comment: just so I am sure I am getting it, this is what it would look like, yes?

```server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com/service;
}```

Comment: Where does 8000 come from? In your question it says 8080.

Comment: was a bit too quick for my comment sry. Yes 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to summarize, I have found the answer.

I can't use jwilder/nginx as that is only for hostnames - so I have to use nginx on the host server to rewrite a rule. I am still using docker-compose with my editted hosts file so that I have easier access locally between containers, but my rewrite rule binds on the port I have exposed.

Answer (score 0):

This redirection should be configured for web server listening to port 80 of domain.com.
Under assumption you've mentioned details of your container, you should publish port 80 from your container
`docker run ... -p 8080 -p 80 ...` 
and configure this redirections in the configuration of nginx.

Comment: Thanks checking if it works. As a follow up what about the reverse proxy nginx docker image, is that a possibility?